# how to setup a secure connection on heroku using rails 5 and devise 4

Tags: ssl, heroku, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have setup devise 4 on my rails 5 app using the default setting and deployed it to heroku. now when I visit the sign_in or sign_up pages I get

```
Your connection is not secure
```

on firefox and

```
Your connection is not private
```

on chrome browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add ssl certificates on heroku -> setting -> ssl using which your site is secure and make changes in `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

and push to heroku.